# Select rows with unique attribute

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following table

```
ind_id      name                 value       date
----------- -------------------- ----------- ----------
1           a                    10          2010-01-01
1           a                    20          2010-01-02
1           a                    30          2010-01-03
2           b                    40          2010-01-01
2           b                    50          2010-01-02
2           b                    60          2010-01-03
2           b                    70          2010-01-04
3           c                    80          2010-01-01
3           c                    90          2010-01-02
3           c                    100         2010-01-03
3           c                    110         2010-01-04
3           c                    120         2010-01-05
4           d                    130         2010-01-05
```

How can I select rows with unique `ind_id` attribute? No matter what the rows definitely will be for each `ind_id`. I need 4 rows in a result set. I'm using SQL Server 2008. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this, you want to use windows functions:

```
select ind_id, name, value, date
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by ind_id order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you only want the ones that appear once, then use:

```
select ind_id, name, value, date
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by ind_id) as NumInds
      from t
     ) t
where numInds = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, the first one is what I need!

Comment: I would hope the OP has some method to determine which row he wants (latest date, largest value, etc..). It can be added to the `ORDER BY` piece so the "correct" rows get returned.

Comment: @TimofeiDavydik . . . Your welcome.  The second one is there because I initially misunderstood the question, so I left it in.

Comment: @N West doesn't matter in my case

Comment: Two years later, thanks for that second answer as well: it turned out to be just what I needed at work today.